# How to replace an existing collection on an Entity Frameworks POCO object

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Let's say I create a new Entity and Save it as follows:

```
UserReport report = new UserReport() {//set the props}
manager.SaveUserReport(report)

Public UserReport SaveUserReport(UserReport report)
{
  using(var context = new ReportDatabase())
  {
    context.UserReports.AdObject(report);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
  return report;
}
```

so far so good

I then read back the saved Report

```
 savedReport = manager.GetUserReports(new int[] {report.Id}).FirstOrDefault();

 Public List<UserReport> GetUserReports(IEnumerable<int> reportIds)
 {
     using (var context = new ReportDatabase())
     {
        var reports = from UserReport in context.UserReports
          where reportIds.Contains(userReport.Id)
          select userReport;
          return visibleReports.ToList();
     }
 }
```

savedReport is now an attached UserReport

The UserReport object has a collection of Columns attached to it.

I want to replace the set of Columns attached with another set (that already exist in the database).

```
 savedReport.Columns = newColumnCollection
```

This fails with the error "The property Columns" on type UserReport_etc' cannot be set because the collection is already set to an EntityCollection"

I've looked at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619904/why-am-i-getting-error-the-property-x-on-type-y-cannot-be-set-because-the-colle): the problem is the same, but I cannot use that solution.

What is the correct way to tackle this?

Comment: What is the type of 'Columns' property? how do you get the 'new ColumnCollection' and what is it's type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - looks like it's just a case of setting the non-navigation properties to not be virtual.

That is one hell of a weird situation, given that the behaviour that is modified is of properties that remain as virtual.

Comment: I would really hate to have to create the conditions under which it is possible to set collections. The code does not explain its intentions, so later on someone may decide to make properties virtual again. Rather, I'd always modify `EntityCollections` by `Add` and `Remove` only. Clear as daylight.

Comment: I don't see why I am forced to go down that route with POCO's. If that was a documented limitation that would be different, but it isn't - it's just something you're left to discover for yourself. 
There is no reason really why you can set a collection once, but then never modify it - except via Add or Remove - to be consistent the collection should be created in the constructor so you ONLY ever use Add or Remove.

Comment: I've switched instead to using the DbContext generator rather than the POCO generator - this creates entities that allow the above out of the box so there is no longer a need to modify the code manually.